# Print size of a vector through an iterator

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, iterator

I'm trying to print the **size** of a `vector`. Sounds easy, but the vector is in a `map`.
Currently I have an iterator on a map looking like this:
`map<string, vector<map<vector<string> , vector<string> > > >::iterator it;`

I am trying to display the size like this:

---

**EDIT:**
The iterator is intialised like this: `it = csvMap.find(commandList.at(lineCount));`

---

`cout<<"Size of vector in Map  after modifying: " << it->second.size() <<"\n"<<endl;`

It's not working, the program crashes.
I think a way would be to make a **temp vector** and fill it with the value `it->second;`
But just to get the size is kind of wasting space isn't it?

Is there a better way to do so?

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT2:** removed old code

---

**EDIT 3:** new code:

```
            map<vector<string> , vector<string> > parameterMap;
        parameterMap.insert(pair<vector<string> , vector<string> > (
            part1_input, part2_output));

        map<string, vector<map<vector<string> , vector<string> > > >::iterator it;

        cout<<"\nSize of CSV Map  before modifying: " << csvMap.size() <<endl;
        //cout<<"Size of vector in CSV Map  before modifying: " << it->second.size() <<"\n"<<endl;


        if(csvMap.size() == 0)
        {
            /*
            * csvMap is empty -> no need to search for something. Just insert the fist entries
            */
            listedParameterMap.insert(listedParameterMap.end(), 1, parameterMap);
            csvMap.insert(pair<string, vector<map<vector<string> ,
                vector<string> > > > (commandList[lineCount],
                listedParameterMap));
            cout<<"CSV Map size: " << csvMap.size() <<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            /* 
            * Search if the Command is already available, if not,
            * add it to the map with its corresponding list of maps (in/output values)
            * find returns map::end if key is not found
            */

            cout<<"Checking if: " << commandList.at(lineCount) << " is already in the list \n" << endl;
            it = csvMap.find(commandList.at(lineCount));
            if (it == csvMap.end())
            {
                /*
                * it = csvMap.end() is true
                * The command isn't found
                */

                cout<< commandList.at(lineCount) << " command not available. Inserting it! \n" << endl;
                listedParameterMap.insert(listedParameterMap.end(), 1, parameterMap);
                csvMap.insert(pair<string, vector<map<vector<string> ,
                vector<string> > > > (commandList[lineCount],
                listedParameterMap));
            }   
            else
            {
                /*
                * it != csvMap.end()
                * The command is found. Append the parameterMap to the vector in the map
                */
                cout<< commandList.at(lineCount) << " is already in the list! Appending parameters on pos: "<< it->second.size()-1<< "\n" << endl;
                it->second.push_back(parameterMap);
            }
        }
        cout<<"\nSize of CSV Map  after modifying: " << csvMap.size() <<endl;
        cout<<"Size of vector in CSV Map  after modifying: " << it->second.size() <<"\n"<<endl;
```

---

I hope someone is still reading this...

I found now that `it.second` seems to be the problem on the first interation. But I don't get why.
Code snippet (also in the code above):

```
if(csvMap.size() == 0)
        {
            /*
            * csvMap is empty -> no need to search for something. Just insert the fist entries
            */
            listedParameterMap.insert(listedParameterMap.end(), 1, parameterMap);
            csvMap.insert(pair<string, vector<map<vector<string> ,
                vector<string> > > > (commandList[lineCount],
                listedParameterMap));
            cout<<"CSV Map size: " << csvMap.size() <<endl;
            cout<<"listedParameterMap: " << listedParameterMap.size() <<endl;
            cout<< commandList.at(lineCount) << " is already in the list! Appending parameters on pos: "<< it->second.size()<< "\n" << endl;
        }
```

**This seems not to work. Although its goning into it. Any idea why?**
comanndList and listedParameterMap are as far as I see OK.

Comment: Please post the iteration loop. We need context.

Comment: You are checking `if(it != csvMap.end())` before using `it->second.size()`?

Comment: Are you sure the `lineCount` you are searching does exist? Do you check for equality to `map::end` after the search?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y lineCount is valid. I checked.   
@Naveen yes I thought it's just 0 if nothing is in there...

Comment: I just tried: Even If I take out this first `cout<<...it->second.size() ...` and I just try to print when it exists for sure, it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
it = csvMap.find(commandList.at(lineCount));
if (it == csvMap.end()) {
  cout << "not found\n";
}
else {
  cout << "Size of vector in Map after modifying: " << it->second.size() << '\n';
}
```

> Either when command isn't found or command is the last

No, the end iterator is not an item in the container.

```
string c = (*it).first;
```

Since this is after the iterator is the end iterator, you have undefined behavior when dereferencing it.

Comment: @Fred look at my comment on CashCows answer pls

Comment: @Beasly: What about it?  The end iterator is not an item in the container, as I said.

Comment: @Fred Yea I got you. I'm just telling why I thought it's like this. So map::end is an empty field?

Comment: @Beasly:  For vectors, `end()` is 1 passed the last element in the vector.  For other containers, it is a special iterator that indicates there are no more values in the container.

Comment: @Zac Howland That means if I look with `map.find` and I get `map::end` I can be sure this element is not existing in this map right? And for vectors it points to the last one... if I got you correctly. I'll modify my code and post the new code.

Comment: For vectors, it points to 1 passed the last element.  Anytime you do a search (e.g. `find`) on any STL collections and it returns `end()`, the element is not in the collection.  `end()` is not a valid element in any STL collection.

Comment: @Fred Nurk @Zac Howland I changed some code... but it still don't work. I don't get how I get to the size without creating another vector...

Comment: @Beasly: Correct. Iterator pairs use a "half-open range" of [begin, end), where begin is the first item, it is advanced until it equals end to get all the items, and end is not "in" the sequence. If begin == end, the sequence is empty.

Comment: @Beasly: I will try to look at the code again later today, to integrate more of your code into my example, but the snippet I have above should replace a large swath of what you have now.

Comment: @Fred Nurk Thank you, as you see above I implemeted it the way you showed me... See you hopefully later then.

Comment: @Beasly: If you update your code to include a complete function (especially with parameters and mention any data members), that usually helps people write better examples for you.  Simplify the test case as much as you can, while making sure it is as complete as possible and still shows the behavior you don't understand.

Comment: @Fred Nurk Actually the method is quite big. As you may see on the quite complex collection. But in future I'll try to stick to your consideration.

Comment: @Beasly: Well, that's why I said to simplify it as you can, without changing the core issue. :) *Complete* code really helps. The biggest help when doing that is also that you gain a better understanding yourself as you narrow down the problem code.

Comment: @Fred Nurk Ok, I'll stick to it :)  
My problem is still that `it->second.size();` is not working in anycase (runtime). It's compiling flawlessly.

Comment: @Fred Nurk (couldn't edit anymore) The thing is why I need to print this value. Accourding to the watch the vector in the map doesn't increase after adding stuff. I had such a "problem" before that the watch was showing wrong things. To check this I'm trying to print the value...

Comment: @Fred Nurk You had some time to look at the problem? Someone else has an idea?

Comment: OK I got it. While testing and copy and pasting code I have accidently overwritten the initialisation of `it`.
I'll accept this answer because this was another main point. Thanks everyone for helping!

Comment: @Beasly: This is why I emphasize *complete* examples; it's too easy to accidentally change something. :) Sorry I didn't get a chance to get back, but that's my life.

Answer (score 1):

Your `it` is pointing to an invalid location. You need to initailize it with the map's iterator. Something like `it = myMap.find("aaa"); //Replace it with actual key` After doing the `find` you need to make sure you are having a valid iterator by checking it agains `myMap.end()`.

**EDIT**

You are using uninitialized iterator here:

```
cout<<"Size of vector in CSV Map  before modifying: " << it->second.size() <<"\n"<<endl;
```

Also, you can not dereference a iterator pointing `csvMap.end()`, it will result in crash again.

**As per EDIT 3**

You are still using the unitialized iterator / iterator pointing to end in `if(csvMap.size() == 0)` and `if(it == csvMap.end())` case. You need to initialize the `it` with the return value of `insert` function like this:
`it = csvMap.insert(....).first;` in these cases.

Comment: As per your EDIT2 the above explanation is still valid. You are using uninitialized iterator. Also, there are many more problems with the posted code while using the iteator.

Comment: @Naveen the find method is working correctly, I checked though watches. Is enough isn't it?

Comment: @Naveen please tell me. I'm still leaning that stuff. I'm not that used to iterators

Comment: @Neveen You are right. Frank Nurk was too. At the end was both things. Seems like at some point I was overwritting my interator initialisation and I didn't notice. Since it's not possible to mark 2 Answers as correct I gave you +1 :) Thank you!

Comment: @Naveen last comment, it's becomming OT ;). This community is really cool. Almost every time you get a response very fast. And in most cases useful info. Like this it's fun to participate :)
See next time. I already have another thing which is a bit wired. maybe tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Map iterators aren't invalidated unless you erased that specific element. That means that you did something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your collection is rather complex.

In order to check the size though you need to know there is an element there at all, i.e. find did not return "end" of your map. If it does, you cannot use the iterator returned.

Of course how you handle this is your own decision, eg return maybe -1 if the string was not found (with 0 indicating it was found but had no content).

Now you have edited your code I immediately spot a bug:

```
   if (it == csvMap.end())
            {

            /*
            * it = csvMap.end() > true
            * Either when command isn't found or command is the last 
            */

            string c = (*it).first;
```

you cannot dereference end (which `it` is)

Comment: I was taking from the API: `An iterator to the element, if the specified key value is found, or map::end if the specified key is not found in the container.`
That's why I thought when not found it points to the last one...

Comment: When it is not found it does point to map::end but that is not the last element, it is one past the last element.